# Multiple Charts in single web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, charts

I am trying to replicate something done in a ASP class webpage, but in a ASP.NET MVC webpage using Razor.

basically a SQL call is made to get some data, I use google.visualization.arrayToDataTable to put the data in from SQL, give it a title then draw said chart.

```
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('topThreeModelNumberST_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
...html code emitted for brevity
<div id="topThreeModelNumberST_div" style="width:400; height:300"></div>
```

and that is done a few times. The outcome is about 6 or 7 charts on this one page.

So as a test I made a HomeController

```
public ActionResult Charts()
{
    List<Models.ModelErrorReports> reports = new List<Models.ModelErrorReports>();
    reports.Add(DAL.DevSQL.GetModelErrorReports("Model1", "efipreQCProError"));
    reports.Add(DAL.DevSQL.GetModelErrorReports("Model2", "eepreQCProError"));

    return View(reports);
}
```

and In my Charts View

```
@model List<FailFixLog.Models.ModelErrorReports>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Charts";
}

<h2>Charts</h2>


    @{
        List<Chart> charts = new List<Chart>();

        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            var myChart = new Chart(485, 300);
            myChart.AddTitle(@item.ModelName);
            myChart.AddSeries(@item.ModelName + "Series",
                xValue: @item.ErrorReports.ErrorDescriptions, 
                yValues: @item.ErrorReports.ErrorCounts);
            charts.Add(myChart);
        }

    }

<table>
    @foreach (var chart in charts)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @{@chart.Write();}
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

now I have tried a few variations to this, but this was my last attempt before I gave up and came here. The result continues to be the same that I only get 1 Chart for Model1. I saw somewhere that I would have to make a view for each of my charts... But that doesn't make sense to me because then I'd have to pass in a List to a Partial view, and seeing as this is my second day writing any sort of web code I cant' wrap my head around that. Just in case you are curious I have a unit test that shows that My List has two ErrorReports, and the data is unique. how do I fix this?

Comment: I know you have a unit test for your code but have you try to put a brake point in your view and check if your list charts actually have the two charts? and your are right there is no reason to create a partial view per chart unless you want to share the charts across multiple pages.

Comment: @MoisesCardenas not a break point, I put in a `Debug.WriteLine(item)` and a `Debug.WriteLine(chart)` and in my Output i see it write twice.

Comment: @Robert Snyder I am also stuck in the same problem. Have you solved this problem?